# What does past mean on a hacker news post?

Tags: hacker-news

[image]

As demarcated in this image. What is its utility?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not a complete answer. It searches the same title and displays the results.

I went to [this page](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=24706670) and clicked on past. It searched the same title i.e *The Nobel Prize in Chemistry 2020* and there were **past** results as well. See screenshots below :

> [image: initial]

> [image: final]

According to the [about page](https://hn.algolia.com/about) on Algolia, where it redirects after clicking *past*

> HN Search provides real-time full-text search for the HackerNews community site. Source code is available on GitHub. The search backend is implemented using Algolia instant search engine.